# python - Getting what's inside of a dictionary key

Tags: python, graph

```
class graph:
    def __init__(self):
        self.vertex = {}

    def agregarVertex(self, vertex):
        self.vertex[vertex] = {}

    def getVertCoords(self, vertex):
        if vertex in self.vertex.keys():
            print self.vertex.get(vertex)
```

So I am trying to get the values that are in that key, when I run the program I get

```
{<Vertex.vertex instance at 0x01DF5120>: 1}
```

So that shows me inside there is a Vertex, how can I access the values of said vertex?

Comment: To know that, we would need to see your definition of a Vertex object.

Comment: Could you explain why the values of your `self.vertex` dictionary are also dictionaries?

Comment: …and just in case your question is because you're not realizing this, what you printed is one of these dictionaries-that-are-values. If you do realize this, then what exactly do you want to get from it? As a `dict` it has the same `keys()`, `values()`, and `items()` methods any other `dict` has.

Comment: @DanGetz I tried to do as you say, but I kept getting an error that said the class doesn't have that method defined.

Comment: @DanGetz I'm using a adjacency "matrix" so each vertex has a list of the vertexes it can go to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access data in a dictionary key just like any other python data type (keep in mind only hashable datatypes can be used as dict keys). Check out the examples below (I'm doing `key.method()` since your example looks like your keys are objects)

```
for key in your_dict:
   value = your_dict[value]
   key.method()
```

Or

```
for key, value in your_dict.iteritems():
    # do stuff with the key
    key.method()
```

Also if you just want the keys of the dictionary:

```
all_keys = your_dict.keys()
for key in all_keys:
    key.method()
```